# How can I use "am not"? Should I put continuous tense behind it or adjective or past tense?

Tags: adjectives, passive-voice, deverbal

I'm not a native speaker and I'm still a novice towards English. Please help me out with this one:

Not

Here is an example:

> I am not tolerate.

Or

> I am not tolerated.

Also, can you guys explain to me which topic I should take a look at to master this kind of sentence?

Comment: The first example is ungrammatical.  The adjective form is *tolerant*, and to say you are not tolerant, you say "I am intolerant".  If you wish to say that you won't tolerate something: *I won't tolerate such behavior.* If you wish to say that someone else did not tolerate your behavior: *They did not tolerate my insolence.*  In the PASSIVE VOICE: *My insolence was not tolerated.* So, your topics: transitive verbs and passive voice.

Answer (score 1):

You want it to be

> I am not _____ (an adjective).

Because it is modifying a noun, in this case I. These are all valid:

> I am not **happy**.
>
> I am not **tired**.
>
> I am not **lazy**.

However, it does not have to be an adjective that modifies a noun. You can have a participle modifying a noun. A participle is a verb in either past or present tense that acts like an adjective. So your sentence could be:

> I am not _____ (a participle).

These are all valid sentences:

> I am not **tolerated**. (Past participle)
>
> I am not **tolerating**. (present participle)
>
> I am not **excited**. (Past participle)

If you want to say that you do not tolerate something, you should use the word 'do' rather than 'am'. *Do* is about your actions (verbs) and *am* is about things that describe you. (Adjectives or participles).

So you could say:

> I don't tolerate _____ (something).